# If I change to Legacy mode for boot, will Ubuntu be damaged?

Tags: 16.04

I am trying out a Debian-based lightweight OS, the OS used for Raspberry Pi, it's called Pixel Raspbian. It's for PCs. Basically, to run or install it on my computer (which I plan to install as dual-boot with Ubuntu), I need to change the boot mode to Legacy.

After I try to install Raspbian alongside Ubuntu, and I wish to boot into Ubuntu later on, can I simply change to UEFI and have Ubuntu running without problems again?

Comment: Just switch to UEFI when you want to boot Ubuntu, you wil not have any kind of problems. I think Ubuntu will run even at Legacy mode, but I'm not sure of that,

Comment: UEFI normally uses gpt partitioning and BIOS uses MBR(msdos) partitioning. It looks like since based on Debian installer it can be either UEFI or BIOSlegacy boot.